# можно ли поочерёдно вынести в консоль ключи из словаря и ввести в них данные

Tags: python, словари

```
a={'Apple': None, 'Pear': None, 'Peach': None, 'Banana': None}
```

мы имеем словарь в котором есть ключи, можно ли сделать так чтобы в консоли автоматически высвечивался ключ, и я записывала в него данный, к примеру

```
>>>Apple
1
>>>Pear
2
>>>Peach
3
>>>Banana
4
```

ну и в конце  `a={'Apple': '1', 'Pear': '2', 'Peach': '3', 'Banana': '4'}`

Answer (score 2):

Однострочник, так сказать:

```py
a = {'Apple': None, 'Pear': None, 'Peach': None, 'Banana': None}
a = {key: input(key) for key in a}
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a={'Apple': None, 'Pear': None, 'Peach': None, 'Banana': None}
for key in a:
    val = input(f"{key}: ")
    a[key] = val
```